# how to auto search data from other site?

Tags: php, web

I have a planning to bulit e-commerce site for travel agent.
And I need to auto search "airline ticket" directly into their server. With out any operator to standby in front of computer. For example :
15 feb 2013, ticket from jambi(djb) to jakarta(cgk).
For that request, i need a scrpit to auto search inside "lion air" server, "sriwijaya air" server, "Garuda Indonesia" server. And get result that can be shown inside my website

Comment: You need to research the APIs available from wherever you intend to fetch data from. Most places will offer one since it helps them sell tickets. Also, the API will likely return info in a universal format. PHP is somewhat irrelevant to this question.

Comment: What exactly does this mean?
> "I need to auto search "airline ticket" directly into their server"

Comment: send something like " ?date=12feb2013&route=djbcgk&adult=1&infant= " to their website server and receive reply about probably cheapest price avaliable

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use RSS Feed. Firstly, make sure that those third party websites provides this service and also point to the information you want. Some CMSs like Drupal also provide RSS Feed service so that you could retrieve other people's updated data into your site. Learn more at http://www.mnot.net/rss/tutorial/

Comment: how about to use script to search data like "15mar2013djbcgk" direct into their server(airline webserver) and receive data from them, and display it on our page.